# Comparing scrambled schedules and hours in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with schedules of employees and contracts. I need to compare the two and highlight which don't match.
A small mock of the file can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/167KNYuEEjwHLyG9NvyFvtGqH4QWxrftrI5qQiSUUHw8/edit?usp=sharing

The main issue is that the schedules and contracts are extracted from different parties, which structure the data in different ways and sometimes the names are not arranged correctly. Also, one side has the name and surname in different columns, while the other has "name, surname" in the same column.

So, what I am interested in achieving is taking value from column A, seeing if it appears in column E and if yes, checking if the corresponding hours are a match as well.

The data that you see is already filtered by some `Query` functions

I'm asking without a proper code example because I cannot think of a way to do a function that does such a complex search and I have not scripted before.

Any idea or point in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Haven't tried that much. I am at an inspiration block at the moment. The names have different structures, so I don't know how to filter all. `Vlookup` with `Regexmatch` does not provide proper results

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected situation from `I need to compare the two and highlight which don't match.`. If your provided Spreadsheet is your sample input situation, can you provide the output situation you expect in your provided Spreadsheet? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fun, try this to highlight all matches, leaving the non-matching entries visible:

```
function myFunction() {

  const Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`Sheet1`)

  const [groupAStartColumn, groupAEndColumn] = [1, 3]
  const [groupBStartColumn, groupBEndColumn] = [5, 7]

  const sheetRange = Sheet.getDataRange().offset(1, 0)
  const data = sheetRange.getDisplayValues()

  const [groupA, groupB] = [[groupAStartColumn, groupAEndColumn], [groupBStartColumn, groupBEndColumn]].map(([start, end]) => {
    return data.map(row => [
      row[start-1].toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z ]+/, ``),
      ...row.slice(start, end)
      ])
  })
  
  sheetRange.setBackground(`#FFFFFF`)
  const backgroundColors = sheetRange.getBackgrounds()

  groupA.forEach((employee, index) => {

    if (employee[0] === ``) return

    const groupBEmployeeData = groupB.filter(row => row[0].includes(employee[0]))

    if (groupBEmployeeData.length) {

      groupBEmployeeData.forEach(result => {

        if (String(result.slice(1, 3)) === String(employee.slice(1, 3))) {

          const groupBIndex = groupB.findIndex(row => String(row) === String(result))
          
          backgroundColors[index].splice(groupAStartColumn-1, (groupAEndColumn-groupAStartColumn)+1, ...Array(3).fill(`#88FF8C`))
          backgroundColors[groupBIndex].splice(groupBStartColumn-1, (groupBEndColumn-groupBStartColumn)+1, ...Array(3).fill(`#88FF8C`))
        
        }

      })

    }

  })

  Sheet.getDataRange()
       .offset(1, 0)
       .setBackgrounds(backgroundColors)

}
```

**Commented:**

```
function myFunction2() {

  // Change to your sheet name:
  const Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`Sheet1`)

  // Change to the corresponding column numbers:
  const [groupAStartColumn, groupAEndColumn] = [1, 3]
  const [groupBStartColumn, groupBEndColumn] = [5, 7]


  const sheetRange = Sheet.getDataRange().offset(1, 0)
  const data = sheetRange.getDisplayValues()

  // Fancy way to get the groups of values, with all special characters removed and capitalized for comparison.
  const [groupA, groupB] = [[groupAStartColumn, groupAEndColumn], [groupBStartColumn, groupBEndColumn]].map(([start, end]) => {
    return data.map(row => [
      row[start-1].toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z ]+/, ``),
      ...row.slice(start, end)
      ])
  })

  // Creates an array for highlighting matches.
  sheetRange.setBackground(`#FFFFFF`)
  const backgroundColors = sheetRange.getBackgrounds()

  // For each employee in group A:
  groupA.forEach((employee, index) => {

    if (employee[0] === ``) return

    // See if there are employees in Group B with matching names.
    const groupBEmployeeData = groupB.filter(row => row[0].includes(employee[0]))

    // If so:
    if (groupBEmployeeData.length) {

      // For each Group B employee that matches the current Group A employee's name:
      groupBEmployeeData.forEach(result => {

        // If timeA and timeB match:
        if (String(result.slice(1, 3)) === String(employee.slice(1, 3))) {

          // Find the corresponding index in Group B,
          const groupBIndex = groupB.findIndex(row => String(row) === String(result))
          
          // and color the current Group A and Group B employee's row green.
          backgroundColors[index].splice(groupAStartColumn-1, (groupAEndColumn-groupAStartColumn)+1, ...Array(3).fill(`#88FF8C`))
          backgroundColors[groupBIndex].splice(groupBStartColumn-1, (groupBEndColumn-groupBStartColumn)+1, ...Array(3).fill(`#88FF8C`))

        }

      })

    }

  })

  Sheet.getDataRange()
       .offset(1, 0)
       .setBackgrounds(backgroundColors)

}
```

Comment: Works good. Thank you very much. A small issue that I spot is that if I delete values, they still remain highlighted even if the cells are empty and I run the script again.

Comment: Awesome! That would be because the background color of the rows are not being reset to transparent/white in this script. I could make an adjustment for that shortly.

Comment: @CaptainsGent Updated both versions.